# How to set RTL in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I add chart in my project with amCharts.

I need strat chart from right page.

I need convert to RTL version.

How to RTL this chart ?

My code is:

CSS code:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
width       : 100%;
height      : 500px;
font-size   : 11px;
}                   
</style>
```

Script code is:

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js">    
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->


<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  } ],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
        "tickLength": 20
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

} );
</script>
```

In HTML code is:

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Its chart.rtl = true;

Check the documentation of amcharts of RTL

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/rtl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by setting RTL.

If you want the chart to support RTL languages and you have RTL headers in your code, you can set `AmCharts.rtl = true;` before any of your chart code is executed so that it handles the text correctly.

If you're simply looking to re-orient the chart axis and data from right to left, you have to do this manually. You can set the value axis [`position`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#position) to `"right"` to move the value axis. To make the data to start from the right, you have to reverse your dataProvider. An easy way to do this is to simply add [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to your dataProvider array in your `AmCharts.makeChart` call.

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395
  } ].reverse(),
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0,
    "position": "right"
  } ],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
        "tickLength": 20
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js">    
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```